# Growth rate of subscribers

Tags: related-rates

[image]

This must be a trick question. I have cracked my brains trying different methods, but still can't figure out.

Comment: What have you tried?  Obviously you can't get a guaranteed answer but you know how many were added after $4$ years, and after $8$ so you could find the best fitting line through those points.

Comment: Side note:  this has absolutely nothing to do with "related rates".

Comment: It is silly to suggest that a model will be accurate enough to tell the difference between the four choices.  That said, you are probably expected to total the number of subscribers in the regions of interest for each year, fit a straight line (why not an exponential?) through them, and extrapolate to 2025.